# UAE residency holder 6 months re-entry

Tags: dubai, uae, residency, emirates

I have residency in UAE, and to keep it active, I cannot be outside the country for more than 6 months (consistent).

In case I travel to UAE, and leave on the same day, would I extend it for 6 more months? (Considering I go through the passport control).